# Could not autowire Mapper from mapStruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

I can't autowire Mapper from mapstruct in Tests. In Test with SpringRunner.class its ok, but when I try with MockitoJunitRunner its not possible.

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
public interface UserMapper {
    UserMapper MAPPER = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    User mapToUser(UserDto userDto);

    UserDto mapToUserDto(User user);

    List<UserDto> mapToUserDtoList(List<User> userList);
}
```

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class nowyTest {
    @Spy
    private UserMapper userMapper;

    private User createUser() {
        return User.builder()
                .firstName("Steve")
                .lastName("Jobs")
                .login("SteveJobs")
                .password("password")
                .role(UserRole.ROLE_ADMIN)
                .build();

    }

    @Test
    public void testMapper() {
        User user = createUser();
        UserDto userDto = userMapper.mapToUserDto(user);

        System.out.println(userDto);
        Assert.assertEquals(userDto.getFirstName(), "Steve");
    }

}
```

It returns NPE :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include the annotation `@Import(yourClass)`? in this case:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Import(UserMapper.class)
public class nowyTest {
   ...
```

You can check [this tutorial](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-init-a-bean-for-testing/) for a bit more information on how to start beans in SpringBoot tests.